# Get max value from django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, max

I am using django rest framework and instead of getting the complete list of an object, I only want to get a specific value, like max(date) for example. Here is the code I am using:

My Serializer

```
class MoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mood
        fields = ('date', 'rating')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Mood.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

My View

```
class MoodList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Mood.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MoodSerializer


class MoodDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Mood.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MoodSerializer
```

My URLS

```
  url(r'^mood/$', views.MoodList.as_view()),
  url(r'^mood/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.MoodDetail.as_view()),
```

So if fire a GET on "max_mood" I want the latest Mood entry from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Mood.objects.all()`, why not sort `Mood` objects by `some_criteria` and get the first one (which will be the *max* one). Like this:

```
mood = Mood.objects.order_by('-some_criteria').first()
```

There is another way but it requires additional queries:

```
from django.db.models import Max

maximum = Mood.objects.aggregate(m=Max('some_criteria')).get('m')
max_mood = Mood.objects.get(some_criteria=maximum)
```

Answer (score 0):

view

```
class MaxMoodView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Mood.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MoodSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        mood=self.get_queryset().order_by('-date').first()
        return Response(self.get_serializer(instance=mood))
```

urls

```
  url(r'^mood/max_mood/$', views.MaxMoodView.as_view()),
```

Comment: I get the following error message: You passed a Serializer instance as data, but probably meant to pass serialized `.data` or `.error`. representation.

Comment: ah ok, make that, `self.get_serializer(instance=mood)`, that should work, I've edited the response as well

Comment: Hmm still getting the same error. MaxMoodView has to be a class, not a function right? (It is a function in your example)

Comment: yup sorry, edited, I'm not really able to test this code because of all the required setup to get a fresh django install going

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got it working with the help of the comments:

view:

```
class MaxMoodView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Mood.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MoodSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        mood=self.get_queryset().order_by('-date').first()
        serializer = MoodSerializer(mood)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls:

```
url(r'^mood/max_mood/$', views.MaxMoodView.as_view()),
```